# CFFI compiled libpango with dependencies? (thai/fribidi/datrie)

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, fedora, pango, cffi

I'm trying to setup a precompiled package for aws lambda, which must contain all the required libraries inside it.

My dependencies are : pango and cairo

So, what I did was go to https://fedora.pkgs.org and download the 64 versions of those, but then when I first executed my code (WeasyPrint/cffi) it gave me the following :

> OSError: cannot load library 'pango-1.0': libthai.so.1: cannot open
>   shared object file: No such file or directory. Additionally,
>   ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called
>   'pango-1.0'

So I just went the the same website mentioned above, downloaded libthai, and then it gave the same error for libfridi, and then for libdatrie.

I'm just afraid this will never stop, is there any compiled pango with all these dependencies?

Worth nothing that I have absolute no clue what I'm doing, just sorta trying to get this to work.

Comment: Did it ever stop? I've got this same problem, so it would be great if you could share your solution!